# JS property accessor on computed property name behaves differently in expression vs assignment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, syntax-error

As shown below, Case 1, Case 2, and Case 3 [access a property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) of an object that contains a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

Case 1 creates such an object in a function argument, while Case 2 creates such an object in an assignment. Case 3 creates such an object in a statement.

Why does Case 3 produce a syntax error?

Case 1

```
$ node -e "var other = 'b'; console.log({a: 1, [other]: 2}[other]);"
2
```

Case 2

```
$ node -e "var other = 'b'; var obj = {a: 1, [other]: 2}[other]; console.log(obj);"
2
```

Case 3

```
$ node -e "var other = 'b'; {a: 1, [other]: 2}[other];"
[eval]:1
var other = 'b'; {a: 1, [other]: 2}[other];
                               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at evalScript (bootstrap_node.js:353:27)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:122:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:121:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

Node version

```
$ node --version
v6.11.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you take curly brackets as [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), not as [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

The error is coming from a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), which can not be a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), because it needs to be an indentifier, and not a computed property.

The first call is defined as expression, which is in the last case not.

To prevent this, you could wrap the curly brackets in round brackets for an expression.

```js
eval("var other = 'b'; {a: 1, console.log('block!') };");
console.log(eval("var other = 'b'; ({a: 1, [other]: 2})[other];"));
```

Comment: Good catch! What is a label? I've never used it (won't ever use it probably).

Comment: @ftor, you may follow the link. a practical use is to break the outer `for` loop with nested loops.